# MATLAB simultaneous recording for multiple cameras

Tags: multithreading, matlab, video-capture

I am currently working on video recording with two cameras and I'm trying to figure out how to start and stop the recording for two cameras at the same time.

I'm using the `getsnapshot` and a `VideoWriter` to get the frames and to store the video file. However, with a for loop they always have a delay between each other, and it compromises the frame rate of the cameras as well.

I tried using `parfor` but it never writes to the video file and seems to have some internal problem. I also tried the `DiskLogger`, but only one video would write properly to the file and the other basically contains nothing.

I would really appreciate any suggestions or short example code to explain how parallel computing would work for running multiple cameras!

P.S. I am using imaging source Dmm 42BUC03-ML cameras in case the information would be helpful. It is an OEM camera.

Comment: You are facing a non-trivial challenge, especially choosing a programming language which does not support multi-threading. For MATLAB I am not aware of any solution. If you are willing to switch to simulink, you could quickly build up a solution. Use two [from video device](http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/saving-video-data-to-a-file.html) blocks and concatenate the outputs to get a widescreen video connecting both data. Then you could easily check if it is really recording synchronous, for example dropping something in front of both cameras and verify both see it at the same height.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get synchronized framerates using software, but you may be able to get acceptable results. Basically you have to reduce the time required to capture each frame to a minimum, and this time sets your maximum framerate (in your case, framerate/2 for two cameras). I have achieved acceptable video recording in matlab using two techniques:

1. Create a timer object to capture the frames on a regular interval.
2. Do not use `getsnapshot`. It is slow. Instead, configure the camera
   manually, and then issue a trigger command to capture an image.

This code illustrates the idea for a single camera:

```
function RecordFromCamera
% RECORDFROMCAMERA Captures still images and appends them to a video file

% % Camera setup
cam_fps = 1; % target framerate. Actual performance depends on hardware.

camInfo=imaqhwinfo;
cam = videoinput(camAdaptor,camInfo.DeviceID,camInfo.DefaultFormat);
% setup camera for individual image mode
triggerconfig(cam, 'manual');
set(cam,'TriggerRepeat',Inf);
set(cam,'FramesPerTrigger',1);


% % Timer Object for capturing camera images
camTimer=timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period',1/cam_fps,'Name','camTimer');
set(camTimer,'TimerFcn',@getCamImage);
% save the camera object for the timer to use
camTimerInfo.cam=cam;
camTimerInfo.video=VideoWriter('camera_video_images.avi','Motion JPEG AVI');
set(camTimer,'UserData',camTimerInfo);


% Test the functionality; capture images for 5 seconds
start(camTimer)
pause(5)
stop(camTimer)
delete(timerfind)


%% sub: getCamImage
function getCamImage(obj,event)
% GETCAMIMAGE gets and saves an image from the camera
%  Intended for use as a TimerFcn

disp('getCamImage')
% disp(event.Data) % this will include a timestamp

% the camera handle is stored in the UserData
camTimerInfo=obj.UserData;

% get an image, add it to video file
try

    trigger(camTimerInfo.cam);
    pic=getdata(camTimerInfo.cam,1);
    writeVideo(camTimerInfo.video,pic);

catch imgEx
    fprintf(1,'getCamImage: WARNING: camera image acquisition error at %s\n  "%s"\n',datestr(now),imgEx.message);
    %stop(obj);
end
```

You would need to create a second camera object for the second camera, but you could use the same timer object for both. You could also create a second timer object for the second camera, but the synchronization between the two timer executions is not guaranteed.